# libgdx get the value of a key

Tags: libgdx, tiles

I'm trying to do collision detection (which I have working well) but now I want to use it for a little more.  I want to check special circumstances for the collision.  Right now I'm checking for containsKey like so:

```
someCell. ... .getTile().getProperties().containsKey("collision");
```

This works fine.  But now I want to use the VALUE of that key to determine what the character hit and continue accordingly.  If the value is null, just a normal hit.  But if the value is a sign, and the user chooses, it can be read.  Or if the value is a chest, if the user chooses to do so they can open it (but check that locked is indeed false first, or the user can unlock it).

The thing is, I've looked everywhere and can't find a way to check the value of the key.  And yes, I can just create a lot of keys but it would be easier to have one key that can carry many values and check and alter them based on user input or game circumstances.  I tried

```
theKey = someCell. ... .getTile().getProperties().containsKey("collision")[.value("someValue");];
theKey.value("someValue");
```

but neither worked.

So, my question to you is this: how can I access and later edit the value of a custom key created in tiled map editor (should have mentioned that earlier, huh)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In fact it's really easy.

`getProperties()` returns a [MapProperties](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/MapProperties.html) object.

So if you look at the documentation it contains a `get` method just like a regular map in Java.

```
getProperties().get("key")
```

Sometimes you just want to retrieve a simple type like a number, in this case, libGDX allows you to pass a type, it prevents you from having to transform the value manually into a number.

```
getProperties().get("key", Integer.class)
```

There is even an overload allowing you to pass a default value in case there is no such key, which is really convenient right?

Comment: Didn't know about the typecasting overload, thanks for the heads up!